# ionic build android error: unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: android, ionic-framework, command-line-interface

[Screenshot of CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG1gm.png)

Hey folks
So i am trying to build my ionic app, and when i run "ionic build android" it gives me an error that is in the screenshot above. I have no clue what it means. it would be great if anyone could help.

Answer (score 3):

I too got the same issue. I installed the latest Java SE Development kit

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

After installing restart PC 
After restarting check environment variables "JAVA_HOME" points to the recently installed sdk "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\" if not edit it.

now ionic build android should work!!

Comment: In m case I changed JAVA_HOME to jdk1.8 but still it taking jdk1.7 why?